# Printing lambda expressions in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to pretty print a Lambda Expression of the following type

`data LamExpr = LamApp LamExpr LamExpr  |  LamAbs Int LamExpr  |  LamVar Int deriving (Show, Eq)`

I think I made some logic errors with my pattern matching, it's bracketing things incorrectly and I'm unsure why. I've tried adding more cases but I think that overcomplicates things.

```
printLambda :: LamExpr -> String
printLambda (LamAbs x f)                            = printf "\\x%d -> %s" x (printLambda f)
printLambda (LamVar x)                              = printf "x%d" x
printLambda (LamApp (LamAbs x f) (LamApp g h))      = printf "(%s) (%s)" (printLambda (LamAbs x f)) (printLambda (LamApp g h))
printLambda (LamApp m (LamApp f g))                 = printf "%s (%s)" (printLambda m) (printLambda (LamApp f g))
printLambda (LamApp (LamApp f g) m)                 = printf "(%s) %s" (printLambda (LamApp f g)) (printLambda m) 
printLambda (LamApp m n)                            = printf "%s %s" (printLambda m) (printLambda n)
```

Example case:

`printLambda (LamApp (LamAbs 1 (LamVar 1)) (LamAbs 1 (LamVar 1))) == "(\\x1 -> x1) \\x1 -> x1"`

Instead I get this:

`"\\x1 -> x1 \\x1 -> x1"`

Answer (score 1):

The data structure in the call to `printLambda` is `LamApp LamAbs(...) LamAbs(...)`. Let's see why the patterns in the function don't match that:

- `LamApp (LamAbs x f) (LamApp g h)` doesn't match because you have `LamAbs`, not `LamApp` as the *second* argument
- `LamApp m (LamApp f g)` doesn't match for the same reason
- `LamApp (LamApp f g) m` doesn't match because you have `LamAbs`, not `LamApp` as the *first* argument
- finally, `LamApp m n` matches any `LamApp` and outputs two `LamApp`s that aren't enclosed in parentheses

Comment: Am I missing a pattern then or something? Im really struggling to see

Comment: @UncleWab, depends on why you're expecting this output and what you're trying to do. Why should this expression be bracketed like that? What's the rule?

Comment: It's lambda calculus, so:
 λx → y z =  λx → (y z) and 
x y z = (x y) z and 
λx → λy → y x = λx → λy → (y x)

these are the general rules

Comment: @UncleWab Which of the pattern matches in your code do you think should match `LamApp (LamAbs 1 (LamVar 1)) (LamAbs 1 (LamVar 1))` (the 1st one, the 2nd one, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

The more common way to do this (note that the `Show` class also works like this) is to add an extra argument to `printLambda` that tells you the precedence context.

```
data Prec = Free | Fun | Arg deriving (Eq, Ord)
printLambda :: Prec -> LamExpr -> String
```

In a `Free` context, there is no danger of the term being "torn apart" by an operation of higher precedence, so no parentheses are needed. The top level of the term is printed in a `Free` context, and the body of every lambda abstraction is also `Free`. The `Fun` context appears on the left of an application. Here, any lambda expression must be parenthesized, or else it will "absorb" the argument (`(\x1 -> x1) x2` becomes `\x1 -> x1 x2`). Applications are fine, though, since they are left associative (`(f x) y` becomes `f x y` stays `(f x) y`). The `Arg` context is the strictest. You can't have a lambda expression, or else it will consume anything on its right (`f (\x1 -> x1) x2)` becomes `f \x1 -> x1 x2`). You can't have an application, or it will be shredded (`f (g x)` becomes `f g x` becomes `(f g) x`).

This helper function conditionally adds parentheses (see built in `showParen`):

```
parens :: Bool -> String -> String
parens True s = "(" ++ s ++ ")"
parens False s = s
```

And this makes everything much easier:

```
printLambda _ (LamVar i) = "x" ++ show i
printLambda p (LamAbs i b) = parens (p > Free) $ "\\x" ++ show i ++ " -> " ++ printLambda Free b
printLambda p (LamApp f x) = parens (p > Fun) $ printLambda Fun f ++ " " ++ printLambda Arg x
```

For your example, this produces `(\x1 -> x1) (\x1 -> x1)`. The output `(\x1 -> x1) \x1 -> x1`, as asked, is generally considered incorrect. It's not ambiguous, but adding stuff to its right implies adding parentheses *in*side the term, which is weird. You could implement it with a new `Prec` called `Block` (the name is because GHC calls this syntax `BlockArguments`)

```
data Prec = Free | Fun | Arg | Block deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

that replaces `Arg`s directly under `Free`:

```
printLambda _ (LamVar i) = "x" ++ show i
printLambda p (LamAbs i b) = parens (p > Free && p /= Block) $ "\\x" ++ show i ++ " -> " ++ printLambda Free b
printLambda p (LamApp f x) = parens (p > Fun) $ printLambda Fun f ++ " " ++ printLambda arg x
  where arg = if p > Free then Arg else Block
```